# SimpleModal form submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit, simplemodal

i have a php page "formpage.php", in there is an form like this:

```
<div id='hiddenform' style='display:hidden'>
<form name="testform" action="formpage.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</div>
```

this form displayed with jquery and simple modal (example):

```
$(".show_hide").click(function(){
$('#hiddenform').modal({overlayClose:true});
});
```

all works fine, the box open with SimpleModal and the form is displayed, but i cant submit the form, when i press the submit button nothing happens. what should i do? the form and the submit works fine without SimpleModal.

i want submit the form (open with SimpleModal) to formpage.phhp (self) and then i use the posted variables further in the script.

thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? If it does something in your js is preventing the default behaviour of the form(might be simplemodal might be something else):

```
$(".show_hide").click(function(){
   $('#hiddenform').modal({
        overlayClose:true,
        onShow: function() {
           $('.simplemodal-data input[type=submit]').click(function() {
               $.post('the_url_where_you_want_to_send_your_data_to', $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function(data) { alert('we have a response and form has been sent!'); })
           }
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: mmh i try it but its the same result.

Comment: but i have in the onShow Option a $.ajax({ }) before $('.simplemodal-data input[type=submit]').click(function() { ...

Comment: would you be so kind to post your javascript so we can see exactly what's in there ... you probably have an event handler for the form submit that returns false and prevents default. As Chris already said you might want to look into firebug/developer tools to see what's going on @ browser level.